# Dynamic form for submit values

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm creating a simple form that allows you to enter data that will then be sent to a DB. In particular I need to know from you how I can create a dynamic form that allows me to enter a number of people specified by the user. Basically if the user wants to add 3 people must present 3 new fields to enter Name, Surname and email, if he wants to add 5, 5 new fields.

I write this, but in my index.php it doesn't work.

```js
// Funzione che permette di aggiungere elementi al form (in questo caso rate)
function Aggiungipersone(person) {
  var numero_persone = person.value;
  var box = document.getElementById('box_person');
  if (numero_persone == "") {
    box.innerHTML = '';
  } else {
    if (isNaN(numero_persone) == true) {
      box.innerHTML = '';
    } else {
      var righe = "";

      // Inserisco una riga ad ogni ciclo
      for (i = 1; i <= numero_persone; i++) {
        righe = righe + "Persona n°" + i + " : <input type='text' name='iname" + i + " size='10' value='" + Cognome + "' type='text' name='isurname' size='10' value=''/><br/>";
      }
      // Aggiorno il contenuto del box che conterrà gli elementi aggiunti
      box.innerHTML = righe;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
Inserire i dati richiesti:<br><br>
<form method="post" action="input.php">
  <b> Richiedente Conferenza:</b><br><br> Nome:
  <input type="text" name="name" size="20"><br> Cognome:
  <input type="text" name="surname" size="20"><br> Email: <input type="email" name="email" size="20"><br> Oggetto Conferenza:<br><textarea name="testo" rows="5" cols="40" placeholder="Specificare oggetto Videoconferenza"></textarea><br>


</form>
```

> UPDATE

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 
Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<title>Prenotazione Videoconferenza</title>
<script src="utils.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function(){

      var val1 =$("#n1").val();
      for(var i=0;i<val1;i++){
      $("#start").append($("#first").clone());
      }
    });
});
?>

Inserire i dati richiesti:<br><br>
<form method="post" action="input.php">
<b> Richiedente Conferenza:</b><br><br>
Nome:<input type="text" name="name" size="20"><br>
Cognome:<input type="text" name="surname" size="20"><br>
Email: <input type="email" name="email" size="20"><br>
Oggetto Conferenza:<br><textarea name="testo" rows="5" cols="40" placeholder="Specificare oggetto Videoconferenza"></textarea><br>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

> In the utilis.js i inserted:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="n1" value="1"><br>

<a href="#" id="add">Add</a>

<div id="start">
  <div id="first">
    Nome:<input type="text" name="name" size="20"><br> Cognome:
    <input type="text" name="surname" size="20"><br> Email: <input type="email" name="email" size="20"><br>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are you calling "Aggiungipersone"

Comment: @mplungjan how can i call the function? I need to put the function after the email field.

Comment: Add a `<script src="utils.js"></script>` and put the script without the script tags in a file called utils.js in the same dir as the php

Comment: @mplungjan So i put the script in a new file utils.jsp. And in my body index.php i have inserted <script src="utils.js"></script> it's right? I have problem with the php code. 
if i insert this code:  
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\index.php on line 12

Comment: Outside the PHP tags

Comment: `<html><head><title></title><script src="utils.js"></script></head><?PHP ...`

Comment: Ok i have inserted this outside the PHP tags. But what about the error that i received?

Comment: It should not give errors.

Comment: Ok i edit my file ( in the first post)  can you please check if i have inserted all the things right ?

Comment: Put `$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function(){

      var val1 =$("#n1").val();
      for(var i=0;i<val1;i++){
      $("#start").append($("#first").clone());
      }
    });
});` in utils.js !!! It is JavaScript not PHP

Comment: @mplungjan Ok and in the index.php how can i call the script??

Comment: And add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` before the `<script src="utils.js"></script>`

Comment: You call it by adding `<input type="text" id="n1" value="1"><br>

<a href="#" id="add">Add</a>

<div id="start">
  <div id="first">` to before the address and `</div></div>` after but inside the form tags

Comment: See the answer from Ashish. I updated the snippet example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** With VueJS - [demo on code pen](https://codepen.io/slaawwa/pen/GBZeqm)

**2)** JQuery

```js
const tmpl = $('#tmpl').html().trim()

$('#btn-add').click(() => {
    let peopleCount = +$('#people-count').val(),
        html = Array(peopleCount)
            .fill(tmpl)
            .join('')
    $('#form-items').append(html)
})

$('#form')
    .submit(() => {
        alert('Submit form by ajax or remove this mathod for default behavior')
        return false;
    })
    .delegate('.btn-del', {
        click() {
            $(this).closest('.row').remove()
        },
    })
```

```html
<div id="app">
    <div>
        <div>
            <button id="btn-add">Add new user</button>
            <label>Number of People:</label>
            <input type="number" id="people-count" value="1" min="1">
        </div>
        <form id="form">
            <div id="form-items" data-empty="Users list is empty"></div>
            <button>Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="tmpl">
    <div class="row">
        <label>
            Name:
            <input class="people" name="name[]">
        </label>
        <label>
            Surname:
            <input class="people" name="surname[]">
        </label>
        <label>
            Email:
            <input type="email" class="people" name="email[]">
        </label>
        <button class="btn-del">Delete</button>
    </div>
</script>

<style>
    .people {
        width: 80px;
    }
    #form-items:empty + button {
        display: none;
    }
    #form-items:empty:before {
        content: attr(data-empty);
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
// content of external javascript file: 

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the link
    var val1 = $("#n1").val();
    for (var i = 0; i < val1; i++) {
      $("#start").append($("#first").clone());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 
Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <title>Prenotazione Videoconferenza</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- here is the external file -->
  <script src="utils.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <input type="text" id="n1" value="1"><br>

  <a href="#" id="add">Add</a>

  <div id="start">
    <div id="first">
      Nome:<input type="text" name="name[]" size="20"><br> Cognome:
      <input type="text" name="surname[]" size="20"><br> Email: <input type="email" name="email[]" size="20"><br>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

once you submit form then you will get array into php file and you can access like this

```
if($_POST['name']){ foreach($_POST['name'] as $name) { echo $name; } }
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks you! I have only a question, if i put the function <script> in a external file how can i recall this in my index.php file?

Comment: you just have to include that script file like this
<script src="custome.js">

and your custome.js file contain that script code.

Comment: I have only a problem: i receive this error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\index.php on line 14

Comment: can you show me your index.php file code? there is just syntax error

Comment: you have inserted $(document).ready(function()  code into php syntax . its wrong. this code is contain in the <script></script> code

Comment: please check and let me know

Comment: I have updated your answer since OP seems to not quite get where to put things

Comment: It's ok now. You can leave it as it is

Comment: Perhaps just have `<!doctype html>`

Comment: Ok thanks man. Now it works perfectly. Just the last question, i can insert normaly the field created in database?

Comment: yes you have to start loop like this 

if($_POST['name']){ foreach($_POST['name'] as $name) { echo $name; } }

Answer (score 0):

you will need something like this:

```js
$("#people").on("keyup", function() {
  $("#form").html(""); // clear the form
  var people = $(this).val();
  for(i=1;i<=people;i++) {
     $("#form").append("<input type='text' name='name[]' placeholder='Name Person "+i+"'><br>");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Number of People:</label>
<input type="number" id="people">
<div id="form"></div>
```

as you see the input names are with [] which means they are arrays.. That means on your server side script you will recieve an array where you have to go through via

```
foreach($_POST["names"] as $name) {
    // do whatever
}
```